# Finite ring has only zero divisors and units

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

> If a nonzero element $a$ of a ring $\mathbb{D}$ does not have a multiplicative inverse, then $a$ must be a zero divisor.

If $\mathbb{D}$ has finitely many elements, then the statement is true. However, I don't see why, as for the infinite case, 7 isn't a zero divisor only because every element $a > 0$ when multiplied by a $b > 0$ gives you $ab > 0$ which has nothing to do with infinity or finite amounts of elements.

Comment: You're right, in $\mathbb{Z}$ zero is the only zero-divisor, $1, -1$ are the only invertible elements, and everything else is neither/nor. Perhaps your ring has some extra conditions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\mathbb D$ is finite, with $n$ elements, and $a\in \mathbb D$ does not have a multiplicative inverse, we consider the elements $$ad_1, ad_2 \dots ad_n$$where the $d_i$ are the $n$ distinct elements of $\mathbb D$. None of these elements is $1$, so the $n$ elements can have at most $n-1$ different values - so two of them must be equal.$$ad_i=ad_j \implies a(d_i-d_j)=0$$Since $d_i\neq d_j$, $a$ is a zero-divisor.

Note that this does use the finiteness assumption in an essential way. $2\in \mathbb Z$ does not have a multiplicative inverse, and is not a zero divisor. There are a number of proofs like this (eg a finite integral domain is a field, not true in the infinite case) which depend on being able to count the elements of a finite object.

Note that in the ring of integers mod $14$, $7$ does not have a multiplicative inverse, and $2\times 7=0$. In the ring of integers mod $15$ we have $7\times 13 =1$ and $7$ is not a zero divisor.

Comment: Excellent @Mark Bennet. Just great.

Comment: Let $ad_1 = 2, ad_2 = 4, ad_3 = 5$. Then three elements have three distinct values, so two of them are not equal.

Comment: @Jossie The point is that there are $n$ products, and there are $n$ elements in the ring. But none of the products can be $1$, so there are only $n-1$ possible values. So two of the products have to be equal. You only get three products if there are only three elements in the ring.

Comment: I just showed that there are three possible distinct values in a set of three elements...I remain confused.

Comment: @Jossie But when you go to $n$ elements there are not enough for all of them to be the same.

Comment: but I just showed it? Maybe I am too dense. What if all $ad_i$ are different? so $ad_i \neq ad_j$

Comment: @Jossie You can have three products which are different from each other in any ring with more than two elements. You can only have $n$ products which are different from each other and also different from $1$ in a ring with at least $n+1$ elements.

Comment: You mean four elements then, not two?

Comment: Also are we assuming $a = d_i$ for some $i$ @Mark Bennet?

Comment: @Jossie the distinct $d-i$ with $i$ running from $1$ to $n$ obviously include all $n$ elements of the ring. Also how many rings with two elements can you construct?

Comment: it's really not getting through my head. Do you have time to arrange a chat and walk me through it step by step?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10643/discussion-between-mark-bennet-and-jossie)

Comment: You say that none of these elements $ad_i$ is $1$. Why not? In a non-commutative ring, this could be true, couldn't it? $a d_i = 1$, but $d_i a \neq 1$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: Consider the map sending $r \to ra$. Use the fact that $a$ does not have a multiplicative inverse, so it's not onto; hence, in the *finite* case, it's not injective. Find a non-trivial kernel element and see what happens.

---

Note that the word *finite* is important here. The proof I've mentioned breaks down since the map $r \to 7r$ is injective, even though it's not surjective. More generally, in infinite rings, elements can be non-units *and* non-zero-divisors.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I don't know the terminology (kernel)? @T. Bongers

Answer (score 2):

Consider the applications $l_a:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$ and $r_a:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$ given by $l_a(x)=a\cdot x$ and $r_a(x)=x\cdot a$. Both are injective if $a$ is not a zero divisor. But, because $\mathbb{D}$ is finite both are surjective too. Then you have left and right inverses for $a$ and you are done.